# AS3 Timer add constructor?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to hold a variable in the timers, so when the callback is called it can use the variables.

E.G. something like this.

```
public function SLOW_DOWN_DURATION(amount:Number, duration:Number):void 
{
    var myIndetifier:Timer = new Timer(2000, 1);
    myIndetifier.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,
                                  timerListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, duration));
    myIndetifier.start();           
}
function timerListener (e:TimerEvent,duration:Number):void 
{
    trace("the duration is " , duration); 
}
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no, unless you want to extend the Timer class. A callback function like that will not work, but you can work around that by declaring it locally. Note that the [`Timer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html%20%60Timer%60) class has some properties you could use.

```
public function SLOW_DOWN_DURATION(amount:Number, duration:Number):void 
{
     var myIndetifier:Timer = new Timer(2000, 1);

     myIndetifier.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(t:TimerEvent) 
     {
         trace("the duration is " , duration); 
     });

     myIndetifier.start();
}
```

Comment: Or otherwise said: Use a closure for the event listener function. By that you can access all variables that the closure captures in the callback.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. It worked like a charm.(you learn something new everyday).

Comment: so did i from @Matthias247 just now :)